# List all the jobs that have been executed within a specified date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is is possible to list all the scheduled jobs that have been executed for a specified date? I'm having a problem where I am not sure if the job has executed yesterday and if all the steps where executed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all the jobs that started within a specified date:

```
declare @date date = getdate()

SELECT
    J.job_id,
    J.name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS J 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS H ON H.job_id = J.job_id
WHERE run_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
GROUP BY J.job_id, J.name
```

To list all the steps for a specified job on a specified date with their status:

```
declare @date date = getdate()
declare @job_name varchar(50) = 'test'

SELECT
    H.run_date,
    H.run_time,
    H.step_id,
    H.step_name,
    H.run_status
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS J
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS H ON H.job_id = J.job_id
WHERE 
    run_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
    AND J.name = @job_name
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

find in this below link it gives all the information about sql jobs

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/

Comment: Telling people to "find it" is not the best approach when answering. Try to summarize the information and be specific where we should look when following links.